# Adding a table causes join error in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a pre-existing report in Crystal which works just fine. I want to add a table from the same database which links on at least 2 fields, in this case:

```
MainEstimateDetails.EstimateHeaderRef = PaperEntries.EstimateHeaderRef
Product.Code = PaperEntries.PaperRef
```

I've linked these 2 up as you can see in the screenshots but as soon as I do I get an error stating that it was unable to load a rowset and that as tables are already linked the join type cannot change. I just want to add this 1 table to the mix then I can complete my report. Attached is a screenshot of my links.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: I think it is just a warning letting you know that your joins might be incorrect. I have noticed on your picture that your are using for other tables left or right outer joins, but for that one you are using inner rather than left outer join.

Comment: `tables are already linked...` are you trying to re link again... in that case you need to first remove the existing link and then relink with the join of your choice...else you will get these errors.